# Ajax sends get instead post

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is html form

```
       <form id="create"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="form-control" name='header' type="text" placeholder="Header" required> 
    <input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple/>
    <div class="button_wrap">
    <button class="btn btn-success" name="create" type="submit"> Save </button>
    </div>
     </form>
```

And this is AJAX query, my form contains both data and set of files.

```
    $("form#create").submit(function(e) {
        var formData = new FormData()($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'create.php',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false

        }).done(function(data) {
            var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);

            if (!dataParsed.success) {
                alert("Done");

            }
            else {
                alert.success("Error");
                $("#create").trigger("reset");                
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

So, I have get request instead post. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `method="post"` in form tag as you are submitting form.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"/>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="create"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input class="form-control" name='header' type="text" placeholder="Header" > 
    <input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple/>
    <div class="button_wrap">
    <button class="btn btn-success" name="create" type="submit"> Save </button>
    </div>
     </form>
     <script>
      $("form#create").submit(function(e) {
        var formData = new FormData()($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'create',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'multipart/form-data'

        }).done(function(data) {
            var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);

            if (!dataParsed.success) {
                alert("Done");

            }
            else {
                alert.success("Error");
                $("#create").trigger("reset");                
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But also it is necessary to provide action in form tag.

Answer (score 1):

> You are event preventing at the **end in your code**. It should be at the
>   **beginning.**

```
$("form#create").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//it should be at the beginning
    var formData = new FormData()($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'create.php',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false

    }).done(function(data) {
        var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);

        if (!dataParsed.success) {
            alert("Done");

        }
        else {
            alert.success("Error");
            $("#create").trigger("reset");                
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Still form submitting with GET.